# What are the most common realistic scenarios where SOC (MCU) is used as target (slave) in I2S commmunication?

Tags: microcontroller, i2s

I need to test the functionality of SOC and I2S software driver for slave mode (target mode.)

I don't want to use another I2S channel in the same SOC as master.  I am looking for a realistic scenario where the SCK and WS signals are generated by master and accepted by SOC.

Comment: Pretty much any digital audio receiver IC like an SPDIF decoder will create this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

That would happen when some other chip or device is defined to generate clocks, whether that is defined by you or because the chip/device can't receive them but only generate them.

Sometimes you want the SOC to synchronize with existing clocks, for example when receiving audio from another device, as you can't send clocks to that device. For example receiving SPDIF.